# Tabs in a Beamer Presentation

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, indentation

I am putting together a beamer presentation with some programming code. However, the verbatim package by default places the code on the left most fringe of the slide. I want the slide to be a little closer to the center of the slide, but still left alligned. How can I do this? can't find anything on google

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{center}
\begin{verbatim}
> library(memisc)
> x <- round(rnorm(3),1)
> y <- round(rnorm(3)*2,1)
> mytable <- genTable(y ~ x)
> toLatex( mytable )
\end{verbatim}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: "I want the slide to be a little closer to the center of the slide, but still left alligned. " what does it mean?

Comment: @xport There needs to be some tabs from the left, but the code still needs to be aligned. so the letters l,x, y, m, and t need to be in the same position.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{verbatim}
> library(memisc)
> x <- round(rnorm(3),1)
> y <- round(rnorm(3)*2,1)
> mytable <- genTable(y ~ x)
> toLatex( mytable )
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

an alternative - especially if you don't want the listing plonked in the middle - might be to use the `columns` environment available in beamer, e.g.

```
  \begin{columns}
  \begin{column}{0.1\textwidth}  % this is empty to create the shift right
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{0.9\textwidth}   % adjust proportions to your liking
 %      insert your code
 %       .....
   \end{column}
  \end{columns}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the `xleftmargin` option in `listings` package to get this sort of formatting in a consistent way across slides:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
aboveskip=1ex,
xleftmargin=2em, % change this value for different indents
basicstyle={\ttfamily \small},
breaklines=true,
breakatwhitespace=false,
showspaces=false,
}

\lstMakeShortInline|  % useful for inline code

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]


This is text before the code listing...

\begin{lstlisting}
> library(memisc)
> x <- round(rnorm(3),1)
> y <- round(rnorm(3)*2,1)
> mytable <- genTable(y ~ x)
> toLatex( mytable )
\end{lstlisting}

And this is after, including some inline code: |round()| and |length()| are both R functions.

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The advantage of `listings` package is you can get fancy with the formatting option, as shown below:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstMakeShortInline|  % useful for inline code
\lstset{%
aboveskip=1ex,
xleftmargin=2em,
xrightmargin=3pt,
breaklines=true,
basicstyle={\ttfamily \small},
breakatwhitespace=false,
showspaces=false,
showstringspaces=false
showtabs=false,
keywordstyle=\color{DarkRed}\bfseries,
stringstyle=\color{DarkBlue},
commentstyle=\color{Olive}\itshape,
language=R, % sets default language
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]


This is text before the code listing...

\begin{lstlisting}
> library(memisc)
> x <- round(rnorm(3),1)
> y <- round(rnorm(3)*2,1)
> mytable <- genTable(y ~ x)  # a comment here
> toLatex( mytable )
\end{lstlisting}

And this is after, including some inline code: |round()| and |length()| are both R functions.

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```